# How can I sort items by custom value in Prisma? (trying to implement "sort by hot" like on Hacker News or Reddit)

Tags: prisma, prisma2, nexus-prisma

I'm trying to implement "sort by hot" similar to what HackerNews/Reddit do, as described [here](https://medium.com/hacking-and-gonzo/how-hacker-news-ranking-algorithm-works-1d9b0cf2c08d).

I want to calculate the rank of a post like so:

```
const age = new Date() - createdAt
const gravity = 1.8
const rankScore = (score - 1) / (age + 2) ** gravity
```

The `Post` model has a `score` value - how many upvotes the post has received, and `createdAt` - the time it has been created. The higher the `rankScore` is, the closer I want the post to be to the top of the list. So I want to take the `score` and `createdAt` values, use them to calculate `rankScore`, and then do `orderBy` by that.

What is the right way to implement this in Prisma?

Right now I'm just returning the list of most upvoted posts like so:

```
prisma.post.findMany({
  where: {
    authorId: authorId,
    published: args.published || undefined,
  },
  orderBy: [{ score: "desc" }],
})
```

So it's easy to rank posts by a field that already exists on the model, but I need to calculate it in realtime, as the page loads, because `rankScore` depends on post's age, and it wouldn't make sense to store something like this in the db.

[Here's](https://github.com/lumenwrites/sketchdaily/blob/master/backend/nexus/postQueries.ts) the actual resolver code I'm writing (see the `posts` query).

Comment: Depends on the expected volume in your app, it is not a good practice to calculate such a field in real-time for every user and every request. 
Consider using some background process to calculate the rank every minute for example and save it in the DB